# Accessing a non JDBC DB using mapreduce

Tags: database, hadoop

I have a database which is not JDBC enabled where I am able to fire a query and get the result using an input stream. I want to access this using a map reduce program.

For a JDBC enabled database there are "DBInputFormat.java" and "DBConfiguration.java" files in Hadoop which take care of accessing the database and getting the result in a user-defined class which extends DBWritable and Writable interfaces.

Is there a way in which I can access the above mentioned non-JDBC database in the same fashion ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your DB supports ODBC. If so you can try jdbc:odbc driver with DBInputFormat. I am not sure if this works as never tried this.

Another option which should be your final option is to implement your own FileInputFormat

Comment: The DB doesnot support ODBC!

Comment: Then I think you need to write your own InputFormat. But I am not sure if there is any other way doing without it!